# Node express session mechanism

Tags: node.js, express, session, mongoose, express-session

I always thought that express session information is stored in mongodb on the server side if `app.use(session({store: mongoConnection}))` is used.

But when I tried to retrieve a session variable set previously on server side with the first browser and I go to the next browser to get it, I can't get that variable. So eventually session variables are stored to cookies on specific browsers? Otherwise I would have gotten that variable regardless of which browser I'm using.

If so, what does that app.use mongo connection do? What is it storing?

Comment: You won't get the same session on different browsers regardless of the storage mechanism. That's the point of a session: it is limited to your time on the page. I don't know exactly how it stores things precisely in Mongo, but it will almost certainly be tied to the User Agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session data is stored on the session store. But a cookie is used to track the session ID for a given browser session. The cookie do not convey session data, just the session ID and some other information for validation purposes. The actual session data is stored on the session store and is not transmitted over the wire. Thus preventing some kind of attacks.

The cookie used to track the session is transferred from browser to server on every request during the session. Therefore you can't access session information from another browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `Session Storage` you're using is used to store session variables in the MongoDB.
After you restart your express.js server, then the same user/browser tab comes back, they are able to get the same variables. Otherwise, these variables will be stored in memory and be erased when your server stop.